# Parse XML String Using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Im just new to c# xml so I need to ask some help to parse a certain xml telegram. Basically what I need is to loop in each nodes to get the UID, ID and value is there a way to do it using LINQ or any other approach?

```
<pre>
PROCESSDATA,ALSS_L01S01,10,20140721005835,<ProcessData tokens="14" cid="1234" uid_1="1234" result_1="P" uid_2="5655" result_2="P" uid_3="8487" result_3="P" uid_4="73695" result_4="P" uid_5="2365" result_5="P" uid_6="12584" result_6="P">
    <TestPlans>
        <TestPlan Name="FOO" Group="FOOFRGP">
            <TestRun Uid="1234" UidType="SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="270.50"/>
            </TestRun>
            <TestRun Uid="5655" UidType="SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="260.50"/>
            </TestRun>
            <TestRun Uid="8487" UidType="SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="260.50"/>
            </TestRun>
            <TestRun Uid="73695" UidType="SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="260.50"/>
            </TestRun>
            <TestRun Uid="2365" UidType="SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="260.50"/>
            </TestRun>
            <TestRun Uid="12584" UidType="PCB_SN">
                <Test Id="INS" Value="260.50"/>
            </TestRun>
        </TestPlan>
    </TestPlans>
</ProcessData>
</pre>
```

Comment: Your XML is invalid. What is `PROCESSDATA,ALSS_L01S01,10,20140721005835,`? Probably, it simply does not belong to here.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the XML is well-formed, but I do agree that the content looks odd.

Comment: Oh, yes, I am wrong. However, it really looks strange. Make sure that it is exactly what you have.

Answer (score 1):

A rather simplistic approach could be done like this, assuming that the `xmlString` variable holds the XML you posted in your question:

```
        var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

        var testRunElements = xDocument.Descendants("TestRun");

        foreach (var testRunElement in testRunElements)
        {
            var uid = testRunElement.Attribute("Uid").Value;
            var testElement = testRunElement.Element("Test");
            var id = testElement.Attribute("Id").Value;
            var value = testElement.Attribute("Value").Value;
        }
```

The `xDocument.Descendants` selects the elements named `TestRun`.
Then we use the `foreach` to iterate through each element to extract the values from the named attributes.

For safety you'd probably want to check that elements and attributes are not `null` before attempting to access any properties, in case your actual XML isn't guaranteed to have this schema for each `TestRun` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can make class from that i usually use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ (or use Visual Studio Function XML to CS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx))
then you can deserialize that XML to an object

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string path)
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        object result;
        using (FileStream reader = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            result = ser.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return (T)result;
    }
```

---

Link to serialization: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

---

string path = path to file you want to load. 
   T is output Object